# How can I see who's VPNed in and for how long?

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, monitoring

I know how to view the VPN sessions currently logged in and how long that connection has been on but I want to be able to view a history of these activities over long periods of time.  I don't think I need employee monitoring software...I just want to see who has VPNed overnight.

We are using Windows 2003.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can enabling logging via RRAS (see screenshot below), and simply peruse the log file as needed.

[RRAS Logging http://www.liketechnologies.co.uk/bryan/rras-logging.png](http://www.liketechnologies.co.uk/bryan/rras-logging.png)